# Extracting text from PNG image in Vb.net 2010 express

Tags: png, vb.net-2010, text-recognition

I have a small PNG image and I need to extract text from it. I tried using tesseract, googled many yes to find a way for it, But nothing worked. How can I extract text from PNG image?

I am using Vb 2010 express.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, hope it was useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this possible using `'Emgu.CV'` [Website here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Download it and import its `dll` files into you application, then see this video to know how it's done : this video can show you exactly how to do it in visual basic : [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjdu8SjEtG0).